# Redirect sub domain and all its files old or new to new url

Tags: .htaccess

I have been searching for this, not sure if it can be done.

I want to redirect a subdomain and all its files old or new to the root domian

I did a basic redirect and the subdomain redirects to the domain just fine.

Problems is if a specific file is added to the subdomain ie. http://sub.maindomain. com/help.htm is brings up a 404 Page not found

Thanks for your help.

Dave

Comment: How did you achieve the basic redirect?

Comment: I searched online for it...

This is the code I used.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forney.onlinethomes.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.onlinetxhomes.com/for-sale%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]



Thanks for any help you can provide.